# machine code reuse in JavaScript VM's

Tags: javascript, optimization, compiler-construction, jit, vm-implementation

Current JavaScript VMs run a JIT compiler, which compiles the JS source code at runtime. The compilation overhead is typically on critical path, although it is possible to do the compilation in parallel. My question is: What are the difficulties of reusing generated machine code across executions? I can think of type difference due to different inputs, etc.

Comment: What do you mean, "is it possible"?  Do you mean possible in theory or are you asking whether VMs actually do it?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I revised the question.

Comment: At least I'm not aware of any JIT compiler that attempts it. Some of the minds behind PyPy consider it way too hard in general to do. For context, at least one of those guys is currently working on adding Software Transactional Memory - including, later on, special JIT optimizations for said STM - to their Python interpreter.

Comment: *reusing generated code across executions* - across executions of what? Are you asking, can browser cache JIT'ted code and reuse it after 1)browser restart 2)site reload 3)page redraw?

Comment: @delnan What about the MS's assembly cache? Don't know much about .NET but that seems to be exactly this. I do know why JVMs don't implement such a cache (which basically boils down to extremely hard with multi threaded classloading, etc.), but it seems to work fine for Microsoft.

Comment: @osgx I see that different techniques and code storages should be used. But in each of the three cases you mentioned, the current JIT compiles the source code again and again. I guess the essential difficulties should be the same.

Comment: @delnan Can you elaborate what kind of "hard" problems that need to be solved?

Comment: See http://mail.python.org/pipermail/pypy-dev/2011-August/008073.html for the mails discussing this.